# format fputcsv with header row and each column etc currently all inserting to first column

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to properly format these fputcsv lines.

Here is the code I am using to write my query to a csv file.

```
$handle = fopen( $dir .'/export.csv', 'w');
  $headers = 'Category Name, ID';
  fwrite($handle,$headers);

foreach( $catresults as $catresult ) {
  $csvcatname[0] = $catresult->name;
  $csvcatimage[1] = $catresult->term_id;
  fputcsv($handle, $csvcatname);
  fputcsv($handle, $csvcatimage); 
}

fclose($handle);
}
```

And this is how it is writing to the csv file. Category Names should be in Category Name column, and ID should be in the ID. If you look you can see that the first Category Name gets inserted into the second column header row along with the header name...

```
Category Name  |  IDShoes
66  
Pants   
65  
Lotions 
64  
findme  
69  
find me 
70  
with space  
71  
Find Second 
72
```

Update

Thanks Barmar its now inserting to two columns. But the first data row is still inserting into my header row. Can I skip 1 row? This is how its showing up...

```
Category Name | IDShoes | 66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `fputcsv` writes another line to the file. If you want the line to have two columns, it must be an array with two elements. You're creating two arrays, each with one element, and writing them separately.

```
foreach( $catresults as $catresult ) {
    $row = array($catresult->name, $catresult->term_id);
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
}
```

Comment: Awesome that works thanks, but now the first data row is still showing up on the header row. Can I skip a row for the headers row?

Comment: Why does `$catresults` contain a header information? You can do `unset($catresults[0])`.

Comment: I don't want to use the db column names, I want to use my own column names so the person viewing the csv file will know exactly what it is... that is why I used $headers = 'Category Name, ID';
  fwrite($handle,$headers);

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Why would the DB column names be in `$catresults`?

Comment: It wouldn't and doesn't... I never said it did. You asked "Why does $catresults contain a header information?" it doesn't so not sure what you were asking...

Comment: You're the one who said that you're getting header information when you use my `foreach` loop. The only way that could happen is if the header is in `$catresults`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you were saying. The problem is that when you write the header line, you're not ending it with a newline.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to do that... I tried $headers = "Category Name, ID, \n"; I tried $headers = 'Category Name, ID';
$headers = "\n";
fwrite($handle,$headers); which makes the first row blank and seems to erase the header row...